# Cannot Change Layout Content In Java Code

Tags: java, android, layout

Very simple question but very weird as well :

I have a class `PanelGlobalActivity` that extends Activity and it is set to the layout `panel_view_activity`. I have a button and a text view, both have IDs.

When I do `findViewById(R.id.*)` it can see my button and my text view but there is no way I can change their values or anything. Like `button.setText("Hello")` would compile but wouldn't change it.

Any ideas ?

Here is my xml file (panel_view_activity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my java class :

```
public class PanelGlobalActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.panel_view_activity);

    TextView label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        label.setText("Test");


}
```

}

Thanks.
Nic.

Comment: can u send your xml and java code ...

Comment: make any change in android manifest ?...

Comment: I think I know why, I have tabs and one of my activity is probably not linked properly to the tab, it only has a layout

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public class PanelGlobalActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   Button someButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);
   someButton.setText("text changed");
   }
}
```

some tips in coding if your using eclipse:

1.Use Ctrl + Shift + O (Imports necessary libraries or whatsoever automatically)
2.Use Ctrl + W (this lists all the possible methods for an object) just like when you're typing the "someButton.s" then press Ctrl + W, all available methods will be showed

Comment: What is different from what I did? Except that your changing the button text instead of the text view

Answer (score 0):

> You don't have any problem on your sample code ... I've run it it's perfectly fine . ..

Comment: It is weird, as if my activity was not linked to the xml

Comment: I'm rally sorry .. I Just copy and paste your code . only one thing i do just import TextView . But work perfectly fine .

Comment: No, nothing, I can change the values directly inside the xml, and it compiles ad everything

Comment: No error message .No change in Androidmanifest.xml.  then What is the problem .... What u got ion emulator ...

Comment: A tablet, but everything worked fine with my other activities, except this one